# send html to window.print function without rendering

Tags: javascript, html, templates, backbone.js, printing

I'm using backbone.js and have 4 rather complex views with different templates and models.  I'm trying to print these 4 separate pages from one button without having to combine all of them and render that page before clicking print. is there any way to do this thats cleaner that combining them all into one superview in backbone?

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: iframes comes to mind as a solution; i printed "contact sheets" of a company website like that and it worked well without fuss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place all that you need to print into a target  container and then use media queries to hide them for screen displays:

```
@media screen { 
   #print_target { display: none; }
}
```

and then for printed media:

```
@media print { 
   #print_target { display: block; }
}
```

The idea being that your assets within  only display when printed.